# Using javascript variables in a seperate file

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I have separated the core of my application javascript into a `functions.js` file which stores my functions which I use when on a desired page:

```
// Functions.js
var MYAPP = {};

(function($) {

    /**
     * Load the Javascript for individual pages in the application.
     */
    MYAPP.loadPages = {
        init: function($page) {
            this[$page]();
        },

        home: function() {
            console.log('On the homepage');
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

I run the file through webpack - as I may be adding other plugins at a later date - by doing `webpack resources/assets/js/functions.js public/js/functions.js`.

Now when I am on my homepage, I place this at the bottom of the body tag:

```
// Homepage.html
<script src="js/functions.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        MYAPP.loadPages.init('home')
    });
</script>
```

and receive the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: MYAPP is not defined`.

NOTE: WHen I do not run it through webpack it seems to work okay...

Comment: This should be perfectly valid. I tested it out locally and see the "On the homepage" console log entry, no error. Perhaps you're running into a caching issue? Try pressing ctrl + f5 while visiting the page.

Comment: I also can't reproduce it. Do you load jQuery before js/functions.js?

Comment: I noticed your comment on your js has a capital F in Functions.js.   But the filename in the script tag is lowercase.  Are you doing this on a case sensitive file system and did you really name Functions with a capital F?

Comment: No reports on your network tab that your functions.js failed to load?

Comment: Can you try to reference `MYAPP` as a property on `window` and see if that makes a difference? I.e. `window.MYAPP = {}` and `window.MYAPP.loadPages.init('home')`

Comment: @Barmar - Yep jQuery is loaded before. Could the issue be that I'm running functions.js through webpack?

Comment: That could be. I don't know anything about webpack, but if it loads the script asynchronously it could cause this problem.

Comment: Update your question, to show how you're actually loading the file, and add the `webpack` tag so people who are familiar with it will see it.

Comment: your function.js should export MYAPP for it to be accessible. Create a second script that imports it and webpack this file instead. I don't know much webpack, but from what I know this should do it.